# Why the topological dimension of C is 2?

Tags: differential-geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

From what I know, the topological dimension of a set has to do with open sets covering it, homeomorphic to `R^{n}`. Then we can cover C with balls, for instance,of `R^{2}`, is that the reason?

Comment: What is the definition of topological dimension? You should include it in the question otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the dimension of $\mathbb{C}$ as a topological manifold. You can cover $\mathbb{C}$ with open discs with of radius 2, where the centres are on the points $a+ib$ for $a,b$ integers, and map each of these discs homeomorphically onto $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2 \leq 2\}$ . Since $D$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, the space $\mathbb{C}$ is a 2-dimensional topological manifold.

Comment: yes! and I think 1 is it dimension as a C manifold (holomorphic)

Comment: Yes, it is a 1-dimensional complex manifold.